# workspace switcher in Ubuntu 14.04Lts

Tags: workspace-switcher

How do I get a small "thumbnail" of Workspace switcher on my launcher using which I can view all my windows and click and open any one of them in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Answer (score 0):

If you have workspace enabled then the launcher shows an icon for Workspace Switcher.
A better idea will be to use shortcut ***super + s***, this displays all the workspaces, you can chose and select even using the arrow keys.
Another solution will be to install ***Unity Tweak*** and set up the hot corners if you want to use the mouse so much.

Comment: Thanks! But I found an easier way. Just type 'Appearance' in dashboard and when the dialog box opens select 'Behaviour' , then click on the 'enable workspaces ' option and the Workspace Switcher icon will appear on the launcher.